# How to find where a defined line crosses a geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the x,y coordinates of where a defined line crosses a geometric series. Given a series and line defined in python as:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 1
r = 1.1
vertical_line_x_axis = 1234567890

# generate terms for geometric series
terms = [a]
for x in range(250):
    a = mul(a, r)
    terms.append(a)

# Generate the coordinates of the points on the graph
x = [0]
y = [0]
for t in terms:
    x.append(t * np.cos(2 * np.pi * len(x) / len(terms)))
    y.append(t * np.sin(2 * np.pi * len(y) / len(terms)) * -1)

# Plot the points
plt.plot(x, y, '-', color='g')
# plot a vertical line for example's sake
plt.axvline(x=vertical_line_x_axis, color='b')
plt.show()
```

How would I go about finding the x,y coordinate of where the vertical line in this example crosses the geometric series without a lot of guessing and checking? Or if I have to guess and check, is there an efficient way to do so?

Here is the output of the graph from the example above for visualizing:
[matplotlib output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6OaN.png)

*Exapanded Explanation/Current Work:*
I'm trying to find where a line crosses a geometric series. Given a geometric series, where a point along the series is being defined as:
$x=t*\cos(2\pi*n/m)$
$y=t*\sin(2\pi*n/m)*-1$
$t=\overset{m}\prod\limits_{n=0} a*r^n$
Where:

- a is a constant given as 1
- r is a constant given as 1.1
- m is the total number of terms in the sequence
- n is the current term index in the sequence of terms
- t is the product notation of the current index in the sequence

In the example given above I am trying to solve for where a vertical line crosses the geometric series. I feel that by solving for a vertical line, I might have an easier time stumbling onto the solution. In that example, I'm thinking that I need to solve for n in the x equation first, then take that n-solution and solve for y.

Comment: So you want to solve $x = ar^n,$ is that right? If so, this is easily done with logarithms.

Comment: Oh! Could you write some pseudo code to show what you mean? Or describe the use of logarithms a bit further?

Comment: To make sure I am understanding this right, please edit your post to include the mathematical formulation of the problem - the code above doesn't tell me the whole story and is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: No worries! I edited the prompt to hopefully give a bit more clarity.

Comment: The error can be big if $m$ is small.